# How do I take over a Git repository from a previous developer through Git Hub?

Tags: git, github

I have recently taken over a development project that has a Git repository linked to a remote repository hosted on Git Hub.

I have full access to the server that hosts the project and has the Git repository.

I have my own account on Git Hub and want to carry on using the current repository.

What is the best way to update the repository on the server, so it uses my remote repository?

The previous developer is no longer available, so I can't access their Git Hub account or contact them to request anything. The repository was hosted as private on Git Hub.

I am not 100% confident using Git and just want some advice to avoid any accidental problems I may cause :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Create new repo on GitHub with correct name.
2. Copy to your clipboard the `https:` clone address found when viewing the repo on github
3. From the git command line inside your repo:

   ```
   > git remote rm *name of old remote repo*
   ```

   The above line disassociates the old repo from your repo (but it could be added back again if you want)

   ```
   > git remote add origin *paste from clipboard*
   ```

   This line above adds a new remote repo to your repo, aliased with the name 'origin'

   ```
   > git push origin
   ```

   The last line will send your commit history and all source code to the new remote. After doing this your code should be visible in github under the new repo.

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks for the quick response. Is there a way of finding out what the name of the old remote repo was called? I have been left in the dark with this and don't know a great deal about Git?

Comment: There sure is. From the command line, enter `git remote`. Git will give you a list of all the remote repositories linked to your repository.

Comment: Nice one, cheers for that Nick. So, if I do the git push origin that will update my new remote repo?

Answer (score 2):

Just create a repo of the same name under your account. Make a new remote or change the url for the existing one and push to it. Done.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. How would I change the remote URL? Sorry for the newbie question on this. Do I need to do a "git add ." to add all the files once the remote is changed?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a copy of the repository, then that is all you need to upload it to GitHub. See the GitHub help page [Create A Repo](https://help.github.com/articles/create-a-repo) for detailed instructions (with screenshots) describing how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have administrative access to the GitHub repo, then you can't do anything with it. It will never be yours. All you can do is create a new repo and let the old one slowly rot away. This will be confusing to some people, so it's best to get hold of the old developer so that he can give you administrative access to the current repo.

If you have write permission to the repo though, you could simply clear out the current one and leave a single file there, like `MOVED_TO_NEW_LOCATION.TXT` or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

Repositories are not taken, but are just pulled (or cloned if it is first time). Once you clone/pull repo, you have everything and you can do anything with that.

1. clone from server
2. push on your private GitHub repo if you want.